# How to check whether the file name contains some strings values in entire file name

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

> I have a File names of around 37k and have 8k of string array. i want to check each individual string in an array is present in those File name and it should return that file name. I have tried below code. But not getting the required answer.

```
  foreach (string result in DifferArray)
                {
                 var res =   result ;
                 var results = files.Contains(res);

                 if (results == true)
                 {

                 }
                 else
                 { 

                 }
                }
              }
```

**I have attached the file names picture below**
[image]

> for example if res has a value of '000000000000000100108979' and filename contain this then it should return the file name.

Comment: what is type of files what it contains?

Comment: What do you want to do if you find matches? Do you want to keep all matching results, or do you only care if the file matches one result? Can you provide a fuller example, as this is not sufficient.

Comment: it contains .jpeg files @PrasadTelkikar

Comment: After finding matches i want to return the file names which is matched @KurtHamilton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick solution could be:

```
var results = files.Any(r => r.IndexOf(res) >= 0);
```

That's because `Contains` search for matching string, not just part of it.
Algorithm could be optimized and something else could be tried, but this is just a wuick fix.

---

**EDIT AFTER OP REQUEST**
To get filename you could use:

```
var filename = files.FirstOrDefault(r => r.IndexOf(res) >= 0);
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filename)) {
  // NOT FOUND
} else {
  // Filename contains your full filename
}
```

Comment: from this can i return that exact file name which it is matched.

Comment: @NiranjanS: get some book and study the basics. Then try to code by yourself and study how people solve the very same things (so learn); do this for years and you'll be far better than me!

Comment: @Macro thank you brother. Tell me how to think about the logic and apply it.